# Parallelizing python function with dictionary as input

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-3.6

I want to call a function `func` in python with a dictionary `dict_a` as input. How can I parallelize these calls so that each elemt (key-value pair) of the dictionary is called as a separate process? I am using python 3.6

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(processes=6) as p:
    p.starmap(func, dict_a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
with Pool(processes=6) as p:
    p.starmap(func, list(dict_a.items()))
```

so it's a list of key/value pairs.